# given a number print the next highest number which has same number of ones

Tags: c++, bit

given a number we have to find next highest number and previous number which has same number of 1 bits in their binary representation

my solution is a brute force approach i.e incrementing the number and counting number of ones 
if it has same number of 1's then print it

for previous number same approach as above one

is there any optimised solution instead of checking all the numbers?

Answer (score 6):

To get the next highest number, simply search for the first instance of `01`, starting on the right and change this to `10`.  Then collapse all the `1`s to the right of the swapped bits into their least significant positions.

Example:

```
 ||
00110000 // 0x30 in hex
```

After swap:

```
 ||
01010000 // 0x50 in hex
```

Next, collapse all the 1s to the right of the swapped bits into the least significant positions:

```
 ||---->
01000001 // 0x41 in hex
```

To get the previous number, search for the first instance of `10` starting from the right, and replace it with `01`.  Then collapse all the `0`s after the swapped bits in to the least significant positions (alternatively, collapse all the `1`s after the swapped bits into their most significant positions).

Example:

```
    ||
01001001 // 0x48 in hex
```

After swap:

```
    ||
01000101 // 0x45 in hex
```

Next, collapse all the 0s to the right of the swapped bits into the least significant positions:

```
    ||->
01000110 // 0x46 in hex
```

Here is a short program that will display both the next higher and lower numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
#define NUMSIZE 8       // The number of bits to display

// Finds the first and second values, swaps them, and collapses.
void swap_and_collapse(bitset<NUMSIZE>& num, bool v1, bool v2, bool c) {
  // Find the v1 immediately followed by v2 in the number.
  int insert_pos = 0;
  for (int i=1; i<NUMSIZE; i++) {
    if ((num.test(i-1) == v2) && (num.test(i) == v1)) {
      // Found them.  Swap the values.
      num.flip(i-1); num.flip(i);
      break;
    } else {
      // Move any c bits to the beginning.
      if (num.test(i-1) == c) {
        num.flip(i-1);
        num.flip(insert_pos++);
      } // if (num.test(i-1) == c) 
    } // if ((num.test(i-1) == v2) && (num.test(i) == v1)) 
  } // for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
} // swap_and_collapse

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Get the number from the command line and display in binary.
  int value = atoi(argv[1]);
  bitset<NUMSIZE> orig  (value);
  cout << "Original Number " << orig.to_ulong() << " is " << orig << endl;

  // Find the next higher number.
  bitset<NUMSIZE> higher(value);
  swap_and_collapse(higher, 0, 1, 1);
  // Find the next lower number.
  bitset<NUMSIZE> lower (value);
  swap_and_collapse(lower,  1, 0, 0);

  cout << "Higher number   " << higher.to_ulong() << " is " << higher << endl;
  cout << "Lower number    " <<  lower.to_ulong() << " is " <<  lower << endl;
} // main
```

Comment: +1 ... thanks for correcting my (now deleted) answer instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to find the next highest number with equal  number of ones

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int c;
cin>>c;
int n=c;
int c1=0;
while(((c&1)==0) && (c!=0) )
{
    c1++;
    c=c>>1;
}
cout<<"the no of zereos"<<c1<<endl;
cout<<c<<endl;
int c2=0;
while((c&1)==1)
{
    c2++;
    c=c>>1;
}
cout<<"no of ones"<<c2<<endl;
cout<<c;
int p=c1+c2;
n=n|(1<<p);
int a=1<<p;
int b=a-1;
cout<<endl<<b;
int mask=~b;
n=n&mask;
a=1<<(c2-1);
b=a-1;
n=n|b;
cout<<"\n"<<a;
cout<<"\n"<<n;

  }
```